# Ajax response option value not inserted to database

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make a category and sub category option in which sub-category will be selected according to the category . I am using ajax for this . In the php script I am using file() to read the sub categories . Now although sub-categories are appearing in my site , its value is not inserted into the database . M confused . Here are the codes :

```
        $arr = file(SUB_CAT_DIR.$val);
echo '<select name="ad_sub_category">';
foreach($arr as $line)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$line.'">'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

And php script to insert into database :

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO
        tbl_classified
    SET
        classified_id = '$id',
        classified_category = '$info[ad_category]',
        classified_sub_category = '$info[ad_sub_category]'
```

Comment: Where are you executing the query? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is this MySQL? You havent said..

Normally I'd have expected to see

```
Insert into mytable (field1,field2,field) values('$field1','$field2','$field3')
```

Have you tried getting the value of $sql as a string, echo it to screen, and then run it direct through the command line, to check errors? or to confirm your SQL statement is being formed? Have you run the mysql_error function in case its complaining its a dup or something (see https://www.php.net/mysql_error)

Comment: OK, but that hasnt answered the question, you didnt post the full query, and as I said, its not in a format I had expected. Nor did you say if you had errors, or what finding the sql string parsed out to, etc.